# Call Function written inside directive from another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a directive as follows,

```
    angular.module('test.directives').directive("resize", function($window) {
      return function(scope, element) {
        var w;
        w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function() {
          return {
            h: w.height(),
            w: w.width()
          };
        };
      };
    });
```

How can i call scope.getWindowDimensions() from another controller? Is it possible?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't really do that. Controllers are not supposed to call functions of a specific directive. If you need a common function for both you might want to include that function in a service and inject it to both the controller and the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should not but if you want it you can do it 
    As shown in this example :-

```
You need to use two way binding by 
scope: {
      control: '='//use for two way binding
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JPh3wZ?p=preview